# Using 'Google Cloud Datastore API Client Library for Java' with Gradle

Tags: java, android, crud, google-api-java-client, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to use the Google Cloud Datastore for a simple read/write function in an Android app.

I went on to [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/datastore/v1beta2) page and compiled this " `compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-datastore:v1beta2-rev31-1.22.0'` " gradle dependency along with the MavenCentral repository.

I then went onto the Batch documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/batch) but the compiled gradle library lacks the Calender class used in this example code:

```
JsonBatchCallback<Calendar> callback = new JsonBatchCallback<Calendar>() {

  public void onSuccess(Calendar calendar, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {
    printCalendar(calendar);
    addedCalendarsUsingBatch.add(calendar);
  }

  public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError e, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {
    System.out.println("Error Message: " + e.getMessage());
  }
};

...

Calendar client = Calendar.builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
  .setApplicationName("BatchExample/1.0").build();
BatchRequest batch = client.batch();

Calendar entry1 = new Calendar().setSummary("Calendar for Testing 1");
client.calendars().insert(entry1).queue(batch, callback);

Calendar entry2 = new Calendar().setSummary("Calendar for Testing 2");
client.calendars().insert(entry2).queue(batch, callback);

batch.execute();
```

What other dependencies do I need to compile to get that class?

I have googled around and looked over other stackoverflow questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-java-client?sort=frequent) and the sample projects [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples) and I can't seem to find a simple demo of how to do CRUD operations with Google Datastore. Can someone please point me in the direction of some comprehensive documentation/ a tutorial that explains how to perform CRUD operations on Google Datastore without using Google App Engine?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in your linked page:

> A complete example of batch using the Calendar API is available in the
>   calendar-cmdline-sample.

The Calenadar API home page is at:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/calendar/v3

There it is shown that the Gradle script requires:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev191-1.22.0'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will look more into that example. I also found  [this](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-java/0.2.3/index.html) library.